# Is it correct to put startup operations in /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart?

Tags: boot

I would like to be sure no miskakes were made.
I put in /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart all startup operations such as

- xset s off
- xset -dbms
- xset s noblank
- call_a_bash_program
- vncserver :1

Is it correct to put these instructions in this file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autostart file is called only when Openbox starts. If it fails to start for some reason, then anything in that file won't be running. As danielbathke mentioned, /etc/rc.local is a more appropriate place for background programs. Anything there will be run at boot regardless. However, since that's run before X11 starts, anything like xset which requires X won't execute correctly, and so the proper location for these things is in the autostart file.

Fundamentally, the difference is things in /etc/rc.local will start regardless of whether or not OpenBox or LXDE is started, while anything in the autostart file will only started when the GUI does.

I'd put `call_a_bash_program` and `vncserver :1` in /etc/rc.local; and `xset s off`, `xset -dbms`, and `xset s noblank` in autostart.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you like to run background programs.

If background, give a try to */etc/rc.local*. It runs before.

If interface programs, try */etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart*. It runs when LXDE session is started.

Comment: Thanks. So, both solutions are correct?

Comment: Late to the party here, but no, trying to run an X program in rc.local is not correct, because X has likely not yet started at that point in the boot process.